# How can I train a model to recognize object with zoomed-in image?

Tags: image-recognition, object-recognition

Humans are good at guessing animals with zoomed-in images from patterns of fur/skin.
(For example, if we saw a black-white pattern fur, it must be a zebra)

I have some experience guessing a car model from an interior/exterior photo without a brand logo.
(based on the dashboard/gear level/air vent or something like that)

I think it would be helpful for my coworkers to have such a model.
(I'm working at a car forum, and I have some limited experience working with TensorFlow).

Is this possible?
Where should I start with?